Short story to read online, "The Weather Man" by Theodore L. Thomas
This story has stayed with me for a very long time. I found it in a couple of anthologies for sale online, but I just want to read this one story again without buying an expensive antique volume.
"The Weather Man" has three protagonists, one for each branch of the organization: political, scientific, and operational. The first is a Congressman who decides to pin his political future on whimsically endorsing a constituent’s request to make it snow in the desert. The second protagonist, a female scientist who comes up with the maths needed to alter the Sun. The third is a bloke who drives a boat across the surface of the Sun in order to enact the solar changes required to change the weather.
Could this story be found archived online?

https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/luminist/SF/AN/AN_1962_06.pdf

It's in this paperback anthology which you can get for $6.34 postpaid if you're in the USA. https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=31689718140&searchurl=ds%3D20%26kn%3Dclarke%2Btime%2Bprobe%26rollup%3Don%26sortby%3D17&cm_sp=snippet--srp0--title1

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm afraid that shopping questions are off-topic.

@DavidW How is it a shopping question? He says he doesn't want to buy it, he wants to know where he can read it for free.

@user14111 So asking how to get a copyright-violating copy is better?  It's still asking "where do I get this," just adding "and I don't want to pay for it."

Shopping questions (and questions about where to obtain items illegally) are off-topic.

Oh, I am so sorry to upset so many of you. I did not mean to break rules.  I was hoping to get the story, and I'm willing to pay for it, but do not want to have it in hard- or paper-back. Kindle would be great. Should I withdraw my question, or may I just edit it?

@DavidW  The story is 60 years old; if it isn't out of copyright it should be; if the law says otherwise it's a bad law; if not outright unconstitutional (I'm not a lawyer) it violates the spirit and intent of the copyright clause, which was put there for the benefit of the general public, not to enrich the publishing companies.

@user14111 It may surprise you, but I actually agree with what you say about copyright.  Personally I think the absolute max should be (if I'm generous) 50 years or life.  But unfortunately that's not the world we live in, and with publishers going after resources like Open Library, I don't think we should expect other resources, like Luminist, to stick around either if they start getting used as places for people to avoid paying for copyright works.  Even if they should be in the public domain.

Edits: Yes, there are organizations that have non-pirate archived some of the anthologies containing this story.
One is Analog June 1962, already mentioned in the comments.
A later book anthology edited by John W. Campbell, "Analog 2", is also archived by Archive.org.
The ISFDB listing for "The Weather Man" by Theodore L. Thomas is listed in a long list of anthologies over 35 years.
Some of the others may also be archived.

Thank you. I will see what those links give me. Should I remove this post, or mark it answered? How do I do that?

There is a checkmark if you want to accept an answer.
Also, the ISFDB listing shows "all" of the anthologies containing it (that ISFDB contributors have found, anyway), and some of them may also be archived.
ISFDB and Archive.org apparently work together.
Finding the story available was the important thing; ISFDB and Archive.org help with that.

I say continue to take the tour, and edit the question, rather than removing it. Your choice.

I found the story and read it, enjoying it even even more  than I did before. Thank you, all, for helping! Don't see any checkmarks, so I'll just leave it alone.

@Angel Look at the votes it has (4 as I write this). There is a check mark below it, to indicate it is the correct answer.
